# Find out which files define a macro

Tags: android, gnu-make

I have an Android AOSP source tree that I'm trying to port to UbuntuTouch. The original tree builds a working AOSP rom, but when I try to build Ubuntu on it, my build continuously fails on many files with different errors that I think I've been able to debug to find out that all of those regard a variable named "Y" that Make would to initialize, but that seems to be confused with an already macro with the same name,thus leading to unpredictable kinds of errors. Indeed I've been able to solve previous problems undefining the macro Y just before the functions that failed into .c source files. It's not a good workaround, I know,and now another one (that I think it's related) popped up, and I'm tired of dirty-patching all these files one by one:

```
system/core/include/utils/StrongPointer.h:101:23: error: expected nested-name-specifier before numeric constant
system/core/include/utils/StrongPointer.h:101:23: error: expected '>' before numeric constant
```

This is the faulty line:

```
100 private:    
101     template<typename Y> friend class sp;
102     template<typename Y> friend class wp;
103     void set_pointer(T* ptr);
104     T* m_ptr;
```

Is it the same issue, as I suspect?
How could I find what file into the whole tree defines globally that macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using -x flag to my shell, I was able to see that on compiler invocation commandline a "-DY" was passed, obviously defining a macro named "Y" and initializing it to 1.
After some investigations I found out that some values taken from ProjectConfig.mk variables are passed to preprocessor as macros, after they have been capitalized. I had wrongly set one of these values to "y", leading the build system to pass it as macro "Y" to the toolchain, and causing all this mess.

Many thanks go to the guys of irc.freenode.org/#gcc.